# Alarm Even Application Closed in iPhone

Tags: ios4, iphone

I am working on iPhone application in which there is an option for Alarm. Is it possible to araise alarm even my application close.

Comment: This can't be implement in our application because application will go to sleep mode when we click on iphone . if you want to ring default alarm then you can access calender through new asset library and can set alarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to a certain degree there is, check out the local notifications programming guide (local notifications are available in iOS 4 and newer).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `UILocalNotification` to set the notifications. Then even your application is not in foreground you will get alerts.

Answer (score 1):

Use local notification available in 4.0. for a tutorial see this [link](http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)