# Turn on iphone from within in app

Tags: iphone, ios, standby

I am writing an alarm clock app for iphone, and I want it to turn on the phone(from standby mode) approx 1hr before the alarm is supposed to go off.

Then I want the app to be active, so I can stream content live without the user having to put the phone in an active-mode.

Any way for an app to switch out of standby?

Answer (score 1):

Without using private api an application can only present alertview (via local or push notification).

And only when user taps "view" button this application can be activated. You can see that in the [link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-free/id332064280?mt=8) you provided - (second to last screenshot)

True, you can always add sound to this notifications - so alarm app can work (and there are many out there) but it can't send itself in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Nope that cant be done, once the app went to the background state you lose control on it, and cannot bring it back

Comment: There exists an Alarm app for iOS. Surely it must work without the user leaving the app in active state. I am not sure whether there is anything special that is allowed for that app, though.

Comment: Please give me the link to this app :)

Comment: =_=". Just do a google search. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-free/id332064280?mt=8

Comment: So @nhahtdh you are saying that this app can get itself active from an inactive background state?

Comment: I only know that there exists an app, since I have seen something working. I don't know which specific app it is. Please test yourself.

Comment: @nhahtdh did you read the question? and the app your are talking about is most likely using private undocumented api, such app will not exist on the appstore maybe it could be found on cydia store :)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way using notifications. Check this SO question for more info:

[Alarm Even Application Closed in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733931/alarm-even-application-closed-in-iphone)